# Would my answer starting with "Ok" be impolite in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, conversation

I'm not a native English speaker.
I've been texting with a main contractor (myself being subcontractor to his business), and these were the closing sentences of that conversation:

Him: Ok cool, I can work with that. I have some projects coming up so will be in touch this week. (thubs up emoji)

Me: Ok. Looking forward to hearing from you.
Thanks.

Im a bit confused if I was correct with the way I answered or was it impolite or disrespectful to start with a short "Ok."? I was thinking to start with "Great.", however that sounded sarcastic to me in that moment.
Most of the time Im trying to be short and on to the point with my answers so Im not appearing inferior or weak. I had quite a few bad experiences where if I was too polite or nice, people tried to walk straight across over me and thought Im an easy target and tried using me or dominating. Therefore Im trying to show a harder front.
Any observations or recommendations?

Thanks.

Comment: This is obviously a highly informal email context, where there's really no point in obsessing over details of "tone". The OP here should concentrate on things that really mark his text out as substandard. For example, [***unpolite*** is barely "English" compared to ***impolite***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unpolite%2Cimpolite&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Will pay more attention on that in the future.

Comment: Since he began his message with 'OK', why do you think you shouldn't?

Comment: It's fine, b4Rni. It's not "too polite or nice". You don't sound servile. It is _short and **to** the point_. (Not "**on** to the point")

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: It is very had to use *Ok* in an impolite manner when writing since you cannot accompany it with a tone-of-voice.  You might sound informal but you would really have to work at it to make it impolite.  If someone told you they had been maimed in a vehicle accident and you responded *Ok*, that would most likely be rude or worse but that type of rudeness is obvious.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but many or most younger (say under 30) English speakers consider a full stop at the end of a text to be impolite or passive-aggressive. In your message above it's fine, but something to avoid imo unless you're texting older people

Answer (score 2):

Saying ok or okay at the start of a message is acceptable, at least in Australian English. However, a word of warning, that sending a message that **only** contained "ok" *may* be considered rude or a bit abrupt, and if the whole message consisted of just "ok." (with the full stop) even more so.

In your case, however, the following sentences remove any chance that a reasonable native speaker would consider the message rude.

Answer (score 1):

There are perhaps a couple of uses of 'okay' that could be considered rude or dismissive, depending on tone and context. A protracted "*ookaayyyy*" can suggest a person is confused by something that has just been said, or that it was somehow strange. The word is also sometimes used as a 'neutral' response to something said - neither acknowledging that an answer was right or wrong, good or bad, and this can come over as a little condescending.

Neither of these applies to your text which seems perfectly polite, especially as it is so informal. Not to mention the fact that both parties in the dialogue use the word. Among its many uses, 'okay' can mean agreement and that you have understood what has been said, so lots of people use it freely.

Comment: I understand, will keep in mind. Thank you.